# how to see core data table in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have create core data and I want to see that data.
i used to see that data Path like this:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/
```

but I am getting after this again Library:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/
```

How do I find the sqlitedb?
I am using Firefox to see data.

Comment: please see the above link, nicely explained to see raw sql statements in core data execution.check for viewing raw sql statemenet section in this link http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find it by going into appDelegate.m, scrolling down to the

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
```

method, and NSLogging the return path, like this:

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

 }
```